# How to merge my uncommitted files with the changes from the repository, within the same branch?

Tags: git, github, merge

I have one file, say, index.html.

I change line 1000-1200 on the file. Another coworker, working on the same branch with me, commit changes on line 600-800 before I had the chance to commit and push.

When I tried to push my commit, my github desktop for mac said something like the head on the repo is greater than my head, so I need to do pull first. When I tried to pull, my github deskop told me that the changes on index.html will *overwrite* my changes.

I just recently use github, for like 1 week. This never happens when I used SVN with TortoiseSVN in the past. It always tried to merge the changes first with my uncommitted files, and then if it can't, it will show me where the conflicted lines are, and which lines I should decided taken from which version. I don't have that option in github desktop. I also don't understand how to do that in git console.

So, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [`stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your local changes, then [`pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) the remote changes and then unstash your local changes onto the updated working tree.

Any conflicts between your changes and the remote changes will show up when you do `git stash pop`.

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: Oh okay, let me try it. Thanks for the explanation on how each command works. :)

Comment: On `git pull`, it gave error like this:
error: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
How should I 'fix them up in the work tree' ?

Comment: @ChenLiYong, It looks like your working tree is polluted by earlier attempts to merge. The simplest solution is to copy out your changed files to another directory, do a `git reset --hard` to make the working tree match the repository, then pull, copy in your changes again, commit and push.

Comment: Now I've already resolved it. I think I'm beginning to understand what happened. I did `git stash`, and then I pulled from the github desktop. Yeah, way to screw everything over lol. And then I did `git pull` again on the command line, and it gave me the error above. Actually, the `git pull` from the desktop is success, but I have conflicts to resolve (I don't know how there's conflict there as I've stashed my changes). After I resolve the conflict and commit, I did the `git stash pop`, and my changes was merged immediately to the head! That's awesome! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChenLiYong, Good job! You'll get the hang of git soon enough and it will become natural to you. Please accept the answer if it resolved your question.

Comment: OOOOOOOH now I really know where's the problem. I don't have to fear to do commit. I can't pull because I haven't commit my changes, and I was afraid to commit my changes, because in SVN paradigm, "commit" equals to "commit + push" in git. And in my office, we shouldn't make a commit before do a pull and resolve conflict first. So in here, I can make any commit as much as I want, and then the sync process will resolve and merge the changes between my local repo and online repo, and that's where I should resolve any conflicts. Thanks!

Comment: @ChenLiYong, That is correct. Also you can do `git pull --rebase` if you want the remote commit to be ordered before your commit.